# Linking sdl2 (undefined reference to SDL functions) in chicken scheme

Tags: sdl, sdl-2, chicken-scheme

I am trying to learn chicken scheme by writing a simple game using sdl. I am trying to create a foreign function to initialize SDL:

```
(use foreigners lolevel)

(foreign-declare "#include <SDL2/SDL.h>")

(define (sdl-init)
  (foreign-lambda* int ((int val))
    "if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
    SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, \"Couldn't initialize SDL: %s\",
                 SDL_GetError());
    exit(1);
  }
  "))
```

I get the errors:

```
undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
undefined reference to `SDL_LogError'
```

So it can't find SDL. Normally in C you would do something like this (from the sdl page):

```
gcc -o test test.c sdl-config --cflags --libs
```

is there a way to add these flags when compiling .scm files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the [sdl2 egg](https://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/5/sdl2). If you still prefer to build your own bindings to sdl2, you can use something like this:

```
csc test.scm -C "`sdl-config --cflags`" -L "`sdl-config --libs`"
```

Also I note that you're still on CHICKEN 4, which is no longer maintained; you might want to consider updating to CHICKEN 5.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that is what I was looking for. I want to make the bindings myself so I can learn how to use foreign code. I am very new to lisp / chicken scheme but have always wanted to learn it. I will upgrade to chicken 5 as well.

Comment: Is there a command to see what version you are using? something like "csc --version"?

Comment: Exactly that :)

Comment: For future visitors, sdl-config may need to be sdl2-config.